# php execute system call and dont wait to finish

Tags: php

how do I execute system call in PHP without waiting for it to finish.

I need to run a script in my server every n seconds. I tried using cron but CRON cant run script every second its minimum is in minutes.

can someone help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a php file, you can do this with

```
 exec (nohup php /path/file.php);
```

nohup will put the proccess in the background, it will run even if you close a terminal or whatever.

To let it run every five seconds a simple

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 1;)
{
   exec (nohup php /path/file.php);
   sleep(5);
}
```

should be enough.

Works with shell scripts and other files, too - just add nohup before your command.

Remember that nohup will create a logfile for every run, to suppress the output use nohup like this:

```
nohup command >/dev/null 2>&1
```